# PHP preg_match ( get url from javascript )

Tags: php, regex, foreach, preg-match

To get the images url i am using this preg_match :

```
preg_match( "/lstImages.push('(.+?)');/", $html, $matches );
foreach ($matches as $mt){
echo $mt;
}
```

in $html ther is a javascript like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var lstImages = new Array();

                    lstImages.push("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-A_8FelFBtA0/U8CbI8mDvNI/AAAAAAABHRk/bz4ysT8qeBk/046.png?imgmax=3000");

                    lstImages.push("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-wkv19o5dCAA/U8CaDZ2VEtI/AAAAAAABHL4/mAGcV8TJbQc/001.png?imgmax=3000");

...

</script>
```

I want to be able to get the urls

```
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-A_8FelFBtA0/U8CbI8mDvNI/AAAAAAABHRk/bz4ysT8qeBk/046.png?imgmax=3000
```

, but ther is no results ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question/code doesn't make much sense - what are you trying to do?

Comment: im trying to get the images urls like (http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-A_8FelFBtA0/U8CbI8mDvNI/AAAAAAABHRk/bz4ysT8qeBk/046.png?imgmax=3000)

Comment: I hope I never have to work on a project that you started lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead if you have to do this using a regular expression.

The regular expression syntax is incorrect for what you are trying to match. Your pattern quotes around the delimiters, I would recommend replacing with single quotes. The single quotes inside of your expression should be  double quotes instead. Also you have [meta characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) that need to be escaped in order to match literal characters.

```
preg_match_all('/lstImages\.push\("(.+?)"\);/', $html, $matches);
echo implode("\n", $matches[1]);
```

Outputs

```
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-A_8FelFBtA0/U8CbI8mDvNI/AAAAAAABHRk/bz4ysT8qeBk/046.png?imgmax=3000
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-wkv19o5dCAA/U8CaDZ2VEtI/AAAAAAABHL4/mAGcV8TJbQc/001.png?imgmax=3000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'/lstImages\.push\("([^"]*)"\);/'
```

Try this.This should give the reuqired images.

Comment: it did not output anyting, the same problem?

Comment: it works but it gives just the first url ? it didnt loop tro them

Comment: @belamil try match_all